# I want know how to get the new photo filters in the camera on my iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, camera

I want to know how to get the new photo filters in the camera on my iPhone 4 because my friend has them on her iPhone 4s. How do I get them?

Comment: I recommend the Camera+ app. They have great filters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the filters you are talking about were added with iOS 8, the recent iPhone operating system update. Unfortunately that update won't install on your iPhone 4.

There are a number of applications available in the App Store that provide similar photo filters though.

Comment: Small side note: filters were added in iOS 7.